# Decode special character in GTM-request

Tags: javascript, special-characters, decode, google-tag-manager

I have a tracking pixel, that I want to implement in Google Tag Manager. The code of the tracking pixel should contain two ids, separated by '|'. In GTM, I created a custom Javascript variable, which contains the required IDs separated by '|' in a string. I then created a custom tag with the tracking pixel and pasted the custom variable with the required IDs into the tracking code. However, when I check what the request generated by the tracking code actually looks like after I trigger it (I do it in Developers Console under "Network"), I see that '|' gets encoded as %7C.

What can I do so '|' does not get encoded in the request?

This is what my request should look like:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXsl?skus=54371200|54168700
```

(I deleted the parts not relevant to my question)

This is what the request actually looks like in the Dev Console:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXsl?skus=54371200%7C54168700
```

This is my tracking code inside GTM, which I implemented as Custom Tag:

```
<img src="XXXXXXXXXXsl?skus={{GTM Variable}}" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden">
```

In the GTM preview console, GTM Variable is a string that looks like this:

`'54371200|54168700'`

So somehow, the string `'54371200|54168700'` becomes `54371200%7C54168700`  in the request, which I need to avoid.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid this? Your endpoint should be able to handle encoded URIs - after all, transmitting data properly is the whole point of encoding.

Comment: Why do you use custom Javascript variable? Why not variable type "Constant"?